# Deciding on User Control to Use at Runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 2 user controls defined on a page:

```
<%@ Register Src="Foo.ascx" TagName="FooControl" TagPrefix="acme" %>
<%@ Register Src="Bar.ascx" TagName="BarControl" TagPrefix="acme" %>
.
.
.
<acme:FooControl ID="myFoo" runat="server" Visible="false" />
<acme:BarControl ID="myBar" runat="server" Visible="false" />
```

At runtime, I'd like to set one of the user control's properties in various locations in the page's code. For example:

```
protected void SomeMethod()
{
     if (isSomeCondition) 
     {
         myFoo.Visible = true;         
     }
     else
     {
         myBar.Visible = true;
     }

     // ...

     if (somethingElse) 
     {
         if (isSomeCondition) 
         {
             myFoo.Prop1 = 123;         
         }
         else
         {
             myBar.Prop1 = 123;
         }
     }

     // ...
}
```

I know that I can have the 2 user controls inherit from a common Interface, but is there another (possibly better) way?

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: And, no, I haven't found no better way than using a common interface. The second best choice as far as I remember is the one you are using.

Comment: I suppose you could use reflection to set the properties, but I really wouldn't recommend doing that. You'd lose type safety. The common interface is the way I'd go. What is it about that solution you don't like?

Comment: More of a curiosity than anything. And thanks for pointing out CodeReview - I didn't notice its existence until you posted the link :)

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** I just realized most of my answer was already covered by the comments to the same question. Apologies to the people who commented, I wasn't "stealing" your content intentionally... :)

no, I can think of *different* ways to achieve the same result (calling properties via reflection or working out something with [FindControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx)) but I can't think of any *better* way than having both your controls implement the same interface.

You could then access the active control via another property, for instance:

```
public IMyControl ActiveControl 
{
  get 
  {
    return (isSomeCondition)? myFoo : myBar; 
  }
}
```